# Enantioselective organic reaction not working

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I'm performing the reaction between acetone and 2-nitrobenzaldehyde catalysed by (L)-Proline, as answered to one of my questions a while ago: [Simple experiments involving enantiomer synthesis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16421/simple-experiments-involving-enantiomer-synthesis)

However, while the literature specified using 1 mmol of (L)-Proline in 20ml of solution, due to the cost of the materials and the budget available, I've only been able to use a fraction of that, around 0.01mmol. I've scaled down the entire experiment to 5 ml to try and compensate for this.

The issue is, I've left this solution reacting for a long period of time (12+ hours) and I'm not seeing any optical activity at all. With the reduced concentrations, I'd have expected to see a lot less activity than the original literature specifies, but to see at least some indication that my reaction is working.

Are the concentrations of (L)-Proline simply too small for any significant reaction to take place? Or can there be some other reason why my reaction isn't working? Note: I'm a chemistry 'newbie', so don't assume anything!

Comment: How are you measuring the optical activity? How are you monitoring the progress of the reaction?

Comment: I am using a polarimeter, and I was expecting to see a progressive change in optical rotation with which I could determine the rate

Comment: Can you measure the optical rotation of proline itself? Based on the optical rotation of the product, can you calculate the expected change in optical rotation for these conditions?

Comment: That's just the problem - there isn't any optical rotation, both before the reaction (aka the pro line) or afterwards

Comment: Based on the concentration of proline and the reported optical rotation, should it be measurable using your instrument? You may be below the limit of detection for the polarimeter.

Answer (score 2):

- The original ["Rutgers' reference"](http://chem.rutgers.edu/sites/default/files/coursefiles/Courses_f09/310/Procedure_Proline_Catalysis.pdf) deploys $2\,\mbox{mmol}$ aldehyde in $20\,\mbox{mL}$ solvent (i.e. starting at $0.1\,\mbox{mol/L}$, or $0.1\,\mbox{M}$) and recommends a stirring of $3\,\mbox{h}$.

Subsequently, you mention $1\,\mbox{mmol}$ per $20\,\mbox{mL}$ solvent (i.e. starting at $0.05\,\mbox{M}$), but without an indication of reaction time.

- But if the starting concentration is lowered further ($0.01\,\mbox{mmol}$ in $5\,\mbox{mL}$ equals to $0.002\,\mbox{M}$ or $2\,\mbox{mM}$), not only the detection of the product becomes difficult. 
  Did you take into consideration that by diluting the reaction you over-proportionally slowed down the advancement of the intended reaction?  Compared to the initially mentioned starting concentration, your reaction starts at a dilution by a factor of 50 (fifty).  This is *more* than a big factor for process involving a bimolecular reaction.

By the way, $0.01\,\mbox{mmol}$ of proline, molar weight of $115.13\,\mbox{g/mol}$ as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proline) would correspond to little more than $1.1\,\mbox{mg}$.